# OSX server 10.6 and umask

Tags: osx-server, permission, file-sharing

I'm trying to set up our server so that file permissions make sense. We have a mac mini running OSX 10.6.7. Through our desktop Macs, we connect to shared folders on that server and save files on it, in Finder, TextEdit, etc.

I've set up a umask, as [documented here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2202). However, this only works from terminal/finder directly on the server. If I save a file to the server using a connected desktop, it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

umask is a **user- and process-specific setting** and can be overridden. Setting a umask on the server does not affect any clients that accessing the shared folder - each of them will use their own default file creation permissions.

If you want to set default permissions on a shared folder, the answer is to use **Access Control Lists** (ACLs), which are much more flexible.

- Here's a somewhat terse [support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH8467) from Apple on setting up ACLs in Snow Leopard Server.
- And here's a slightly [friendlier guide](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-acl-permissions-in-os-x-lions-server-ap.html).